# temporary change magit-display-buffer-function

Tags: magit, counsel

I have create this little helper to easy jump to my last used git projects, I using `magit-status-internal` to open a status buffer and I set `magit-display-buffer-function` so that the status is open in a full
frame,  that works but I don't want the change to affect other magit calls should I just set `magit-display-buffer-function` to its previous value after the call to magit-status-internal or is there a better way to archive that.

```
(defun git-repository-p (d)
  (file-exists-p (concat d "/.git/config")))

(defun find-git-repository (d)
  (if (equal (file-name-directory (directory-file-name d)) d)
      nil
    (if (git-repository-p d)
        d
      (find-git-repository (file-name-directory (directory-file-name d))))))

(defvar recentf-list)

(defun counsel-recentp ()
  (interactive)
  (require 'recentf)
  (recentf-mode)
  (ivy-read "Recentp: " (delq nil (delete-dups (mapcar #'find-git-repository recentf-list)))
            :action (lambda (f)
                      (with-ivy-window
                        (setq magit-display-buffer-function 'magit-display-buffer-fullframe-status-v1)
                        (magit-status-internal f)))
            :caller 'counsel-recentp))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I haven't really tried this, but can't you just use a `let` binding instead of the call to `setq`?

```
(with-ivy-window
  (let ((magit-display-buffer-function 'magit-display-buffer-fullframe-status-v1))
    (magit-status-internal f)))
```

... something like that